# easiest way to know the position of minimum values in array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, position, minimum

i have this block of code how can i find the minimum value position in the array of readings .
e.g if the minimum is readings[10], is there a way i could write the code

```
int count = 0;
long readings[20] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
for (count = 0;count <21;count++;){
readings [count] =  time2[count] + (time3[count] * 60) + ( time4[count] * 3600);
}
```

i was actually using if statements before like this.
 `if  ( (readings[0] <= readings[1]) && (readings[2]) ) {}`
but now i want to compute and compare 20 numbers(readings[0]) to  (readings[20]) in the array , i would appreciate if there is a way i can just know the smallest  element position  in the array .

Comment: You're trying to initialize each element of the array using a for loop and now you want to get the smallest element's position of the array?

Comment: Hi, try to use std containers (std::array, std::vector (if the size isn't fixed)). There are implemented methods for these containers. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element

Comment: @Chelz - the standard algorithms work on raw arrays too.   `std::min_element(std::begin(readings), std::end(readings))` will give a pointer to the minimum element (or the first found, if more than one element has the same minimum value).   `std::distance(std::begin(readings), std::min_element(std::begin(readings), std::end(readings)))` will convert that to a (signed) integral index.

Comment: For the OP - looping from `count = 0` to `count < 21` means your code writes past the end of `readings`, so causes undefined behaviour.   Loop to `count < 20`.    I assume the extra `;` in the `for` is a typo.

Comment: @Peter that's nice to know, thanks

Answer (score 6):

[`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) will do the work for you:

```
auto index = std::distance(std::begin(readings), std::min_element(std::begin(readings), std::end(readings)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet is, in my opinion, the way you should proceed with.

```
tmp_inx = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    if(readings[i]<readings[tmp_inx]){
        tmp_inx = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just loop through the array and save the position where you find the minimum value. Something like this

```
long readings[20] = ...;

long min_reading = readings[0];
int min_position = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 20; ++i)
{
    if (readings[i] < min_reading)
    {
        min_reading = readings[i];
        min_position = i; // save minimum position
    }
}
cout << "the minimum position is " << min_position << endl;
```

Comment: `int i = 1`? Shouldn't it be zero?

Comment: No because you've already considered the zero reading in the two lines before the for loop.